# Email Service for Angular 2 application

Tags: angular

I am developing an application in angular 2 and i need an emailing service. What is the best option that i should take on? I want to create an email service that can send single emails, bulk emails, schedule emails and lot more. Any advice ?

Comment: That's a backend task. Angular would just send HTTP requests to trigger the sending of the email (or to pass the data to construct the email) but the actual sending will be done server-side.

Comment: @AngularFrance  Thank you very much. Are there any references you could direct me to read more or maybe a plunker (example)?

Comment: That's too broad of a question. It really depends what type of backend you're using. All major backend languages (PHP, Python, Java, Node.js...) have specific techniques to send email. You need to search the docs for your backend language of choice. If you don't have or don't want a backend, you could also use an email API such as https://www.mailgun.com/.

Comment: This isn't Angular question, as it was said.